# Replacing old 60's junction box with recessed lighting

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling, junction-box, old-work

I want to replace a light fixture that was put in the 60s with recessed light.

The junction box looks to be held in place by a metal 'u' shaped bar, with the 'u' bend going over the junction box.

Would I have to cut in to the drywall (this is a basement ceiling) and remove from below?

If I don't want to do that, is there any recessed lighting that would be compatible with a 4" junction box?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Much easier to go with a flat panel LED fixture.  Not recessed but close. No modifications to ceiling.   https://www.amazon.com/AVANLO-Thickness-Equivalent-Dimmable-Junction/dp/B07K789T4J/ref=sr_1_20?dchild=1&keywords=flat+panel+led+lights&qid=1587663605&sr=8-20

Comment: Yeah, I would go a surface mount LED as well. Replacing the box is going to be dificult

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a [flat panel LED fixture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K789T4J).

It is Not recessed but it is very thin and unobtrusive. No modifications to ceiling would be required.

The other option is to cut a new hole adjacent to the box ( *same joist cavity* ) and fish a wire to the hole for new [No-can recessed light](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ND1L263) and put a cover plate on the old box.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll look in to the flat panel LED.